# Microsoft Graph does not work with ADFS?

Tags: graph, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I get the following message when trying Graph Explorer.

Does Microsoft Graph support ADFS authentication?

Regard Dat.

Sign In

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. 
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 61daeae5-d95b-4d2f-a32c-880021f0b437
Timestamp: 2016-07-20 21:17:14Z
AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Microsoft Graph and the Graph Explorer leverage Azure Active Directory for authentication.
Azure Active Directory can be federated to ADFS.

The error you're seeing indicates that while your account is indeed an Azure Active Directory account, you are not an administrator.

Graph Explorer requires an administrator to sign in and consent before non-administrators sign in and use it.

You have two options at this point:

1. Contact your administrator and ask him/her to sign in and consent to the application
2. "Manually" query the Graph via it's rest endpoint. You can find a sample of how to do this here: http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis

Comment: Saca, Could you step me through the process.
I am currently try a prove of concept, therefore No Application is created. I am using PowerShell to do the testing now.

Comment: Here is the working PowerShell Script.
`
Clear-Host
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (MyEmail, $secpasswd)

$messagesuri = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages'
#$messagesuri = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/Inbox/messages'

$messages = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $messagesuri -Credential $credential
$messages.value | % {
 $mailitem = $_
 $subject = $mailitem.Subject
 $messageid = $mailitem.Id
 $subject
}
`

Comment: Actually, there's a new version of the Graph Explorer that I believe no longer requires admin permissions. Can you try again and see if it works for you?