# Where could I find some information about ADFS authetication for Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I did not found an answer for such specific question.

I have checked:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs

I have also found the thread below, but it was not useful:

[Microsoft Graph does not work with ADFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491072/microsoft-graph-does-not-work-with-adfs)

I would like to know how to get ADFS and Microsoft working together in a .NET MVC app. I did not found anything for that in https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain *how* that thread wasn't useful? You haven't asked an on-topic question here yet.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I meant that thread was not useful TO ME. How about you? Anything useful to say regarding the subject? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what the question exactly is. What is your exact issue? Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

Per the other thread you reference - Office365/Azure AD can be federated with ADFS (using AD Connect or Azure AD PowerShell for example).  Once this is in place, an app can use AAD to sign users in (using their corporate creds), and acquire access tokens to Microsoft Graph to access the signed-in user's cloud data (after consent is provided by the user).

We also support a preview of "[hybrid deployments](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support)" which allows an app to be written once against Microsoft Graph, but can access a user's Outlook data whether the user's mailbox is hosted in Office365, outlook.com (personal email) or in an on-premises Exchange mailbox.

If this is the information you are looking for, please update your question to be more specific about your scenario, so that we can provide more help.